# Update a single column in a row when value is NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to Update a singular cell in a record using SQLPLUS. In a table called `CUSTOMER` I, the `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` column is not a Primary Key and is also a null value. I mistakenly made two of the `CUSTOMER NUMBER` values the same.

[image]

My question now, is there any way to `ALTER` and `UPDATE` a singular cell in a record? I need to change the `Adams` row to `412` instead of `522`.

Comment: Surely the challenge is in identifying which row to update? Once you can do that, updating one column is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This is why primary keys are important!

You have to be VERY CAREFUL to update on another (hopefully unique) field, or you might update more records than expected. Since Adams, Sally appears twice in your example, the street name ***does*** differ though for the 522 entry that you mention.

This assumes, of course, that there is only **ONE** address with this name!
(and that there is not another "16 ELM" in the table that might not appear in your example output)

Try: `UPDATE CUSTOMER set CUS=412 WHERE STREET='16 ELM'`

If there are other entries having the same address, then those would also get updated. If you had instead used `WHERE LAST='Adams'`, then you would have updated 2 records.

Answer (score 0):

update customer
set cus = 412
where rowid not in (select max(rowid) from customers group by cus);

This should serve your purpose. Please provide a feedback on the outcome.